# In GROUP BY, can we reference a parent query's column?

Tags: sql, group-by, correlated-subquery

If yes, the first query below should be correct, but shows error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.
If not, the third query should also throw error...

```
 SELECT   POSSIBLE.ENAME, POSSIBLE.DEPTNO, POSSIBLE.SAL
 FROM     EMP POSSIBLE
 WHERE    SAL >
   (SELECT   AVG (SAL)
    FROM     EMP AVERAGE group by possible.deptno having
        POSSIBLE.DEPTNO = AVERAGE.DEPTNO) ;

 SELECT   POSSIBLE.ENAME, POSSIBLE.DEPTno, POSSIBLE.SAL
 FROM     EMP POSSIBLE
 WHERE    SAL >
   (SELECT   AVG (SAL)
    FROM     EMP AVERAGE group by average.deptno having
        POSSIBLE.DEPTno = AVERAGE.DEPTno) ;

 SELECT   POSSIBLE.ENAME, POSSIBLE.DEPTNO, POSSIBLE.SAL
 FROM     EMP POSSIBLE
 WHERE    SAL >
   (SELECT   AVG (SAL)
    FROM     EMP AVERAGE group by possible.deptno) ;
```

Comment: Once again, it seems that the first query is wrong either because of 'group by' OR 'having'... Either way, for whatever reasons, the next two formations should also be erroneous. Give inputs...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first query should use `WHERE`, not `HAVING`. A `HAVING` clause is used to filter based on aggregated (i.e. non-group) values, not to filter the rows involved in the grouping.

Aside from that, you don't even need grouping in the first query.

```
SELECT   POSSIBLE.ENAME, POSSIBLE.DEPTNO, POSSIBLE.SAL
 FROM     EMP POSSIBLE
 WHERE    SAL >
   (SELECT   AVG (SAL)
    FROM     EMP AVERAGE WHERE
        POSSIBLE.DEPTNO = AVERAGE.DEPTNO) ;
```

Comment: Second query shows no error despite 'HAVING'. All correct queries mentioned above show same correct output

Comment: @popstack: That's because you're using `HAVING` on a grouped expression (the rules for what is allowed in `HAVING` is the same as what's allowed in `SELECT`). In the first query, you're grouping by `possible.deptno`, which is why `average.deptno` is not allowed in the `HAVING` clause (it doesn't matter that they're the same; the expression itself is not in the `GROUP BY` clause).

Comment: That's what I asked... Why second query is correct? It is grouped by 'average.deptno' ... and ...  having POSSIBLE.DEPTno = AVERAGE.DEPTno) ;                 Why no errors here???

Comment: @popstack: Because the only expressions in the `HAVING` in that query are either grouped (`average.deptno`) or from the outer query. In the first query, you have `average.deptno` in the `HAVING` but it is not grouped.

Comment: @popstack: The third will likely select the first value retrieved, since you're not limiting the data being grouped at all. You should use the first query in the form that I presented above.

Comment: Also, please remember that you need to accept an answer once it's answered your question. You haven't done that on any of your previous questions, so please take a moment to visit them and mark the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   POSSIBLE.ENAME, POSSIBLE.DEPTNO, POSSIBLE.SAL  FROM     EMP POSSIBLE  WHERE    SAL >    (SELECT   AVG (SAL)
    FROM     EMP AVERAGE group by possible.deptno having
        POSSIBLE.DEPTNO = AVERAGE.DEPTNO) ;
```

i think the error **ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY** is referring **AVERAGE.DEPTNO** in the having clause in the inner query